# setting input values using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple html file containing the monthly salary of employees and must calculate the tax payable for each salary! I use an "add" button to add more employee textfield which creates a new class of div containing the similar div! On onchange event of the salary textfield I can not set the tax value of the appropriate employee!

Unfortunately I can not upload the screenshot so I put all code to make my question as clear as possible!

This is the html code:

```
<div id="all_emps">
    <div class="em_area">
        <label>Employee 1</label>
        <input type=text required  />
        <label>Position</label>
        <input type=text required  />
        <label>Monthly Salary</label>
        <input class=em_sal type=text required  size=10 />
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
        <label>Salary Tax</label>
        <input class=em_tax type=text required size=10 readonly />
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
        <a href="#" id="add_emp">Add</a>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
        <a href="#" id="del_emp">Remove</a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;
$("#add_emp").click(function () {
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("class", 'em_area' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<br><label>Employee '+counter+' </label> <input id=em_name name=em_name type=text required  /> <label>Position</label> <input id=em_post name=em_post type=text required  /> <label>Monthly Salary</label> <input class=em_sal name=em_sal size=10 type=text required  /> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <label>Salary Tax</label> <input class=em_tax type=text size=10 required />  ' );
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#all_emps");
counter++;
 });

 $("#del_emp").click(function () {
if(counter==2)
{
    alert("Can not remove the only employee!");
}
else{
    counter--;
    $(".em_area" + counter).remove();
}
 });
  $('#em_area').on('change' , '.em_sal', function() { // Fire the change event

var salary = parseInt(this.value);
var dueTax = 0;
if(salary < 5000){  
    alert('Salary less than 5000!!');
}
else if(salary >= 5000)
{
    due_tax= salary/100;
    due_tax= salary - due_tax;
}
// This will get the corresponding tax input for the employee..
$(this).closest('div').find('.em_tax').val(due_tax) ;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored a bit. You have now one `all_emps` div, and one `div` per employee, with `id="em<counter>"`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cWft/9/)

html part :

```
<div id="all_emps">
    <div id="em1">
        <label>Employee 1</label>
        <input type=text required  />
        <label>Position</label>
        <input type=text required  />
        <label>Monthly Salary</label>
        <input class=em_sal type=text required  size=10 />
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
        <label>Salary Tax</label>
        <input class=em_tax type=text required size=10 readonly />
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp

    </div> 
    <a href="#" id="add_emp">Add</a>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
     <a href="#" id="del_emp">Remove</a>    
</div>​​​​​​
```

js part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 2;
    $("#add_emp").click(function() {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
        newTextBoxDiv.attr("id", 'em' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.html('<br><label>Employee ' + counter + ' </label> <input id=em_name name=em_name type=text required  /> <label>Position</label> <input id=em_post name=em_post type=text required  /> <label>Monthly Salary</label> <input class=em_sal name=em_sal size=10 type=text required  /> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <label>Salary Tax</label> <input class=em_tax type=text size=10 required />  ');

        $("#all_emps div").last().after(newTextBoxDiv);
        counter++;
    });

    $("#del_emp").click(function() {
        if (counter == 2) {
            alert("Can not remove the only employee!");
        } else {
            counter--;
            $("#em" + counter).remove();
        }
    });
    $('#all_emps').on('change', '.em_sal', function() { // Fire the change event
        var salary = parseInt(this.value);
        var due_tax= 0;
        if (salary < 5000) {
            alert('Salary less than 5000!!');
        } else{
            due_tax = salary / 100;
            due_tax = salary - due_tax;
        }
        // This will get the corresponding tax input for the employee..
        $(this).closest('div').find('.em_tax').val(due_tax);
    });
});
```

​

Comment: guess I need to use .after() instead of .last() to make em div incrementally be added! and also the counter must be initialized with 2!

Comment: It works fine up there in jsfiddle but doesnt in my computer! What might be the problem? is jquery file not supporting some parts of the code?

Comment: To see if the problem is with my jquery file I linked an updated source of jquery which is: 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"> </script> But it keeps doing nothing when I enter numbers in em_sal textfield! Pleaaaaaaaaaaaase Help me!

Comment: @Distributor Hmmm, I made a few edits, so maybe you didn't get the right one... Maybe try to recopy the code actually in answer.

Comment: But I think I got the correct code, Just copy and paste your code in jsfiddle to my local file!

Comment: Ohh yesssssssssss..It works well!! Thank you so much Raphael Althaus!